# Playing a Movie from MPMediaItem (iPad/IOS5)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod

I need to play a movie already synchronised from iTunes to Apples 'Movies' App on a iPad, in a view.

I can play a movie from the bundle using MPMoviePlayerController OK. I can get a media Item of all movies (NSArray of MPMediaItem's using MPMediaQuery). However the MPMoviePlayerController only accepts an NSURL - not an MPMediaItem.

So, how can I play a movie when all I have is a MPMediaItem of the movie? Is there another object other than MPMoviePlayerController that does this? Several posts explain how to 'get' a media item but not how to 'set' an item.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

each `MPMediaItem` has an URL which can be accessed with [`valueForProperty:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaEntity_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMediaEntity/valueForProperty%3a).

I don't know if you can use that to play it in `MPMoviePlayerController` though. In theory it should work.

```
NSURL *url = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
```

---

EDIT: Looks like it's not possible to use that.

> *MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL*
>   A URL pointing to the media item, from which an AVAsset object (or other URL-based AV Foundation object) can be created, with any options as desired. Value is an NSURL object.
>   The URL has the custom scheme of ipod-library. For example, a URL might look like this:
>   ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=12345
>   **Usage of the URL outside of the AV Foundation framework is not supported.**

from: [General Media Item Property Keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008211-CH1-SW22)

Comment: Thanks this has worked! It would have taken a long time to find out '[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]' - Not very intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSURL *url = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:   url];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[myView addSubview: player.view];
[player play];
```

i think this should work..

MPMediaItem is inherited from MPMediaEntity which has the method valueForProperty:

Comment: Thanks, you and Matthias below gave a solution